# predefine message facebook send button 

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to use the fb send http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/ button but would also like to predefine the message so a user does not have to think about what to say and only fill out the recipients. Can this be done? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Facebook APIs do not let you to format or send messages on behalf of you to your friend. That would be pretty spammy.

Comment: The only exception is News Feed where you can have Stream messages from your app

Comment: I am not asking to send the message through API. Only to have a 'default' message instead of the empty default message. It would be easier to send the message but also help out my users.

Comment: The same. I consider that as a sending message, as user needs to only press Ok button :)

Comment: and add a recipient but yes...it makes it easier :)

Comment: @Gulip Did you manage predefined message in text area field?If yes please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try to use javascript and jquery in order to set a text message in the textarea when your user click on the Send button, just look for the class of these elements and create a quick script.

Comment: The dialog is opened in an iframe which is located on different domain. It means you cannot access its content via JavaScript.